# Postgres Sql - How to apply Offset on Timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

My offset-date-time object I store in the DB with 2 columns, one **timestamp**(UTC) column
and another corresponding **offset**.

For example, if I get: **2017-05-01T16:16:35+05:00**, in the DB I will store this data in 2 columns the first **timestamp** will have the value in UTC (2017-05-01T11:16:35), and the **offset** column will have the +5 timezone in minutes so -300 in minutes.

Now I need select this data from DB, but I need to apply offset and again get the data  that was entered: **2017-05-01T16:16:35+05:00**.

I can achieve this in Java by selecting both values and applying offset.
But I want to do DB level?

Comment: Hi, sorry u are right, I should have mentioned +5 timezone.  I will correct it. But the idea is the same. I store in db as utc and offset separate. Now I need to retrieve data applied time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, if I get: 2017-05-01T16:16:35-05:00, in the DB I will
> store this data in 2 columns the first timestamp will have the value
> in UTC (2017-05-01T11:16:35), and the offset column will have the -5
> timezone in minutes so -300 in minutes.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html. see: UTC offset **for PST (ISO 8601 extended format)**
So **2017-05-01T16:16:35-05:00** is an timestamptz type value, therefore at utc timezone value should be **2017-05-01 21:16:35+00**!

---

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8eba3eb20d6208a47145513af436ec77)

```
create table test_timestamp(
    org text,
    tsz timestamptz,
    ts timestamp,
    offsettz interval
);
```

org as timestamp or timestamptz input text. First we **assume** that org text format ending with something like '1999-01-08 04:05:06-8:00', the pattern is last part is like **[+/-]99:99**. the last part refer to the offset time to the UTC.

- tsz cast text to timestamptz
- ts ignore timezone, only timestamp.
- offsettz interval can be positive or negative. offsettz is the pattern **[+/-]99:99** text cast to interval.
  Then create a trigger, the only input is org text, all other 3 column would be computed via trigger.

---

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION supporttsz ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.tsz := (NEW.org)::timestamptz at time zone 'utc';
    NEW.ts := (NEW.org)::timestamptz at time zone 'utc';
    NEW.ts := NEW.ts::timestamp;
    IF SUBSTRING((
    RIGHT (trim(NEW.org) , 5)) , 1 , 1) = '-' THEN
        NEW.offsettz := (
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org)
            , 5))::interval;
    elsif SUBSTRING((
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org) , 5)) , 1 , 1) = '+' THEN
        NEW.offsettz := (
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org)
            , 5))::interval;
    elsif SUBSTRING((
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org) , 6)) , 1 , 1) = '-' THEN
        NEW.offsettz := (
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org)
            , 6))::interval;
    elsif SUBSTRING((
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org) , 6)) , 1 , 1) = '+' THEN
        NEW.offsettz := (
        RIGHT (trim(NEW.org)
            , 6))::interval;
    ELSE
        NEW.offsettz := '0::00'::interval;
    END IF;
    RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tg_supporttsz_test_timestamp
    BEFORE INSERT ON test_timestamp FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE supporttsz ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,  I can't add comment because of low score.
I just tried below script, hope it can help.

```
create table test (id int, col2 timestamp, col3 int);

insert into test values(1, '2017-05-01T11:16:35', -300);

select * from test;

select (col2 - col3 * INTERVAL '1 minute')::varchar(32) ||  (col3/60) :: varchar(20) ||':00' from test;
```

We can finally get below result:
2017-05-01 16:16:35-5:00